# How far do you need to play solo before you can do co-op?

Tags: destiny-2

Supposedly the prologue of Destiny 2 is solo-only, but I'm not quite clear when it's officially over and you can do co-op. Once you get your ship or a bit later? The quip I found said

> In order to actually unlock the co-op feature, players will need to complete the Prologue mission and an additional level afterward.

Answer (score 7):

The moment you end up in the european dead zone and clear a mission there called 'Spark', you can meet with other players. It will start you off in a social zone called the 'farm' which is an instance others players are in.

Comment: The mission you have to complete is called "Spark."

Comment: Ah thank you for reminding me, I remember the contents of it but not the name.

Comment: If I don't remember the name, what's some minutiae from it?

Comment: Read the comment above and check the post @Nick T already put name in thanks to first commenter

Comment: @Blazeoffury49er yeah, I get the name, what is that mission, I don't know if I did it...

Comment: You fly out to the shard of the traveller and get your light back. It is the first mission in the EDZ, I did not put it in the post bc of potential spoilers.

Comment: I just ran through it on a char; I think you could safely say things like "after you get a bunch of new gear", or "you see a bunch of other people at the farm".

Comment: Which i did dude, 'which is an instance others players are in' ill go change the wording though to make it better.